# Can't update values with multiple checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to create a user-selected pricing experience where clicking a checkbox (to select list-size) will change some numbers of a pricing graph.

I have the idea of it set up, and even had an **[extremely simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/AXsVY/302/)** working.

```
$('input[name="optionsRadios"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='small') {
        //change to "show update"
         $(".change1").text("green");
         $(".change2").text("yellow");
    } else if ($(this).val()=='med') {
        $(".change1").text("pink");
        $(".change2").text("white");
    } else if ($(this).val()=='large') {
        $(".change1").text("red");
        $(".change2").text("blue");
    } 
});
```

But when I move it over to my **[live site](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3755975376&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP)** it doesn't seem to want to preform the script. It is also not throwing any errors specific to my script.

## Here is the JS of the full version:

```
/* Auto Pricing Updater */
$('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='pricing1') {
        //change to "show update"
         $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("179");
         $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".01");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("214");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".01");
         $(".upgrade-price").text(".0025");
    } else if ($(this).val()=='pricing2') { 
         $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("699");
         $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".005");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("714");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".006");
         $(".upgrade-price").text(".002");
    } else if ($(this).val()=='pricing3') {
         $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("3,499");
         $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".0025");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("3,514");
         $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".00325");
         $(".upgrade-price").text(".00075");
    } 
});
```

and for the sake of having it, a **[simplified JS fiddle of the live site](http://jsfiddle.net/AXsVY/304/)**.

Any help in solving this issue is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an errors, because your Javascript/JQuery code does not have any errors.

Looking at your fiddle, the elements you are trying to change are not marked with the classes referenced in your JQuery code.

There are no elements (at least in the fiddle) with a class of pricing-engage-chng, pricing-engage-chng-additional, pricing-crm-chng, pricing-crm-chng-additional, or upgrade-price.

When you do `$(".pricing-engage-chng")` you are selecting all the elements with a class of pricing-engage-chng.  If you wanted to select, for example, the element currently marked `<span class="pricing-number">79</span>` then you need to add the pricing-engage-chng class like this: `<span class="pricing-number pricing-engage-chng">79</span>`

Comment: That's very weird.. I put them into the live site and it was not cacheing (I think), then copying the HTML brought over non-cached text. Will update, then re-comment. be back in a few.

Comment: Update: I fixed the cached classes on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXsVY/306/), but still don't seem to see it happening on the [livesite](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3755975376&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP)

Comment: I entered the $('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){ ... }); into the Chrome console, and it works on the live page. You're right though, that it's not working on the live page on load. The code itself is correct. My assumption would be that other javascript on the page is preventing this code from getting called. Try two things 1) Move the script tag where you include SalsaMain2016.min.js to the bottom of the page. Does this work? 2) Remove all the js files (except for the jquery library), and see if it works. Then add back the js files one by one to isolate the problem.

Comment: Well I cleared the salsamain.js file and only have that code in it, still doesn't work. You are correct however about loading it through console. Currently looking for a way to write it as an OnLoad function.

Comment: Looking at your code again, I realized your code is actually within two document.readys. Within the $(function(){... }), you have a $(document).ready(function(){...});  Within $(document).ready you have the $('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){ ... }) code. In Jquery, $(function(){... }) is equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){...}), so you essentially have your code within two (document).readys.  Remove the unnecessary inner $(document).ready(function(){ and see if that works.

Comment: VKK, I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow exactly what you mean? `$('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){` are you saying there are 2 within this statement?

Comment: $('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){..}) is within $(document).ready(function(){...}) which is itself within $(function(){... }). $(function(){... }) = $(document).ready(function(){...}), so you can remove the $(document).ready(function(){...}), and place $('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){..}) directly within $(function(){... }).

Comment: I figured out that I need it wrapped in `$(function(){ });` for some reason it didn't read it when it wasn't.
Thanks for the continued troubleshooting!